# Running method throughout entire application - IOS

Tags: ios, background-process

I have a method that saves an array of images to my database. This happens in the background so there is a possibility the user pops the navigation controller leaving multiple images unsaved.

```
 - (void) sendToCloud{
    sending = true;
    if (cloudQueue.count != 0) {
        [[cloudQueue firstObject] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             if (succeeded) {
                [cloudQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                [self sendToCloud];
            }else{
                [self sendToCloud];
            }
        }];
    }else{
        sending = false;
    }
}
```

Should I send a notification to my `NavigationController` to run this method so that wherever the user goes, the method will continue to run? How can I keep this method running?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot ways you could lose those images. The app could get killed for example. Then they're gone, whatever you do.

A good approach is to save all the images into a Core Data model so they are persisted on disk. You then create a model controller that coordinates the background upload. The model controller doesn't belong to any view controller and works until they've all been sent. It can delete the images once they're in the cloud (or not, if preferred).

That way, when the app starts you can also check if there are unsent images. The model controller just carries on uploading.

The benefits of this approach are that images don't get lost and it tolerates poor network connectivity (the images stay in the model until  they can be sent).

If you really don't want to use Core Data, then you could save the images to disk yourself. If you put them in a subdirectory in the Caches directory then your controller could just keep sending until the subdirectory was empty (deleting as it went along).